# Using ReflectiveInjector at parent to provide services to child views

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have a situation where I would like to use a directive to synthesize the DI hierarchy of pre-configured services so that child components and directives can freely inject them.  What I've tried is to inject the `Inject` service at the parent, and then use `ReflectiveInjector` to resolve and create the hierarchy.  From within that parent Directive, all of the resolving seems to work (i.e., I can `get()` any of the tokens.  However downstream components and directives cannot inject them (either using `@Inject` or otherwise).

[Here is an example application in Angular 5](https://angular-gitter-wmzhot.stackblitz.io/).  This also doesn't work in Angular 4.

The example is extremely trivial, I know.  But imagine the situation where within the builder directive, you use a configuration to dynamically inject multiple tokens/services which downstream components may need.

Is there a way to inject services/tokens at a child that were originally resolved in a parent using ReflectiveInjector?

Comment: This is not supposed to work. You can provide your injector as service, then child components can inject your custom injector and request values using `myInjector.get(key)`

Comment: Alright, thanks for clarifying.  I was under the impression that resolving using the injected Injector, one was able to cache new providers into the existing context.

Comment: No, existing injectors can not be modified. This is why lazy loaded modules need `forRoot` to register providers in the root scope, because there is no way to add providers to the root scope once it is created.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up going a similar route to `forRoot` / `ModuleWithProviders` as you suggested but providing end users with a function that builds a `Provider[]` list according to their configuration (the idea being they could use the method either at the module level or Component).  Now the remaining issue is a warning that the imported function name not being statically analyizable (but I'll make a different post for that.)